# Apple Magic Mouse 2 not scrolling - Magic Mouse 1 works! (Windows 10 / PC)

Tags: bootcamp, windows, bluetooth, driver, mouse

I have been using an Apple Magic Mouse "1" for quite some time now on my Windows 10 PC and I was very content except the damn batteries that needed replacing every once in a while. So I bought an Apple Magic Mouse **2**. Shouldn't be that difficult, right? Disconnect the "1", connect the "2" and go!

Nope. The mouse works fine except it *doesn't scroll*.

- I've (re)installed the latest `AppleWirelessMouse64.exe` from the Bootcamp support software (tried both 5.1.5722 and 5.1.569) and also the BlueTooth driver.
- I've tried switching the mouse off and on again (disconnecting, reconnecting), rebooting, unpairing and (re)pairing
- I've tried [MagicUtilities](https://magicutilities.net/); at first it installed but then my mouse became near unusable. The pointer would jump instead of move with second+ intervals, the mousebutton(s) didn't react to anything. Even not after rebooting, again trying all of the above with pairing, unpairing, switching off and on etc. On boot the mouse worked fine; I could click and move it without issue until MagicUtilities loaded (in the taskbar). Then it seemed to break. So I then uninstalled the software. However the mouse *still* kept "jumping". It turns out MagicUtilities also installs a driver <strike>but doesn't *uninstall* it</strike> didn't remove it in my situation. Uninstalled the driver manually, which failed for some reason on several occasions, but, a couple of reboots and "persuading" later I had my mouse (or mice) finally back to where I got started.

But, still, the MM1 scrolls just fine, the MM2 doesn't want to. Here's some more of my findings:

- Both mice connected doesn't seem to cause any trouble but, for every step above, I also tried with only the MM1 or MM2 connected.
- When only the MM1 is connected and I open the Mouse settings [it has a "scroll-wheel" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ra5x.png). When the MM2 is the only mouse connected the [tab disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntrty.png). When both are connected the tab shows.
- When I go to the hardware tab there's a difference between both mice's "location". One, the MM1, shows "[On Apple Wireless Mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCUYi.png)", the other, MM2, shows "[On Bluetooth HID-device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1z5E.png)".

Since I've exhausted all of my ideas (I also tried looking at the registry to find differences etc. (didn't change anything ofcourse)) I tried to go back to giving MagicUtilities another, rather reluctantantly, shot; however: it [won't install anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYwEw.png): "`The required Magic Mouse Driver installation failed. Error code is -2147418112`". Again, I've tried rebooting etc. but that doesn't help anything.

Oh, I have even tried:

- Connecting the MM2 to my MacBook air. Scrolling works fine. Ofcourse.
- Since my MM1 has a name like "`<joe's mouse>`" I *even* tried renaming the MM2 to "`<joe's mouse>`" on the MacBook and then going back to my PC, connecting the MM2 (solely) and hoping it would pick up the MM1's settings. To no avail, as expected. But there's always that little spark of hope...
- Disabling [Bluetooth Battery Monitor](https://www.bluetoothgoodies.com/), thinking it may interfere somehow. Didn't make any difference. It does, however, report two mice and two battery levels which is nice.

So now I'm sitting here, at my desk, with a MM1 and MM2, simultaneously (and consecutively) connected and working all fine and dandy EXCEPT for the frikkin' scroll on the MM2 whereas my MM1 scrolls just fine. Thats €89 down the drain...

So... now what? Anybody with **the** tip to get my beloved MM2 to work on my Win 10 64bit machine?

Comment: I can save you some time and just give you working drivers, thanks to brigadier solution from here -> https://github.com/Rain9333/MagicMouse2DriversWin10x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a LOT of trial-and-error I have these findings:

I had to completely uninstall [Bluetooth Battery Monitor](https://www.bluetoothgoodies.com/); this was the main culprit. Simply "exiting" wasn't enough, only when disabled on startup I was able to make some progress and only after actually uninstalling everything started working as it should. Somehow these two applications seem to interfere / bite eachother.

I had issues with the mouse "jumping", not registering any clicks (it did, until Magic Utilities was loaded), I had it showing up as "not connected" in Magic Utilities and I had it actually show up as connected whenever I unpaired and re-paired but then in less than 10 seconds it would go back to "not connected" etc. It caused all sorts of strange problems. Clicking / moving the mouse at times caused beeps to come out of my speaker (like in the good old days when the keyboard buffer was full or when an application hung in Win 9x).

Uninstalling BlueTooth battery monitor fixed all my problems. Which kind of sucks since I liked it...

Answer (score 2):

Here is [Magic Utilities](https://magicutilities.net/).

At this point in time, we are not sure what went wrong in your specific case, but **our drivers do uninstall** when uninstalling the Magic Utilities.

You can always uninstall **any** Windows driver with Windows **pnputil** from the command line. First enumerate all drivers, to find the relevant eomXX.inf, then do a **forced** uninstall of that oemXX.inf file.

Note: The BootCamp drivers from Apples official webpage **do not support** the Magic Mouse 2.

We'll contact you via email to help you to solve your specific problem.

The Magic Team

Comment: Hi and thanks (and awesome!) of you to reply here! I have answered your email but, as I suggested in my reply, maybe we can keep it on here so other people also can read along and maybe find solutions to their problems as well. I have rectified my question about the driver not being removed; I guess that would be something specific to my system that happened to fail or something. Sheer bad luck... I'll look into using pnputil (never used it before) and try to figure out how to clean my system of the Apple drivers (and yours) and try to get MagicUtilities (re)installed again for another shot.

Comment: Also, maybe offtopic, I'm using [sharpkeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) with [this config](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/wiki/Using-an-Apple-Magic-keyboard) (disclaimer: I wrote the Wiki article but am otherwise unrelated). I'd like to keep using it since your MagicUtilities doesn't allow me to freely configure some keys (or I don't see it in the screenshots at least for F16-F19 for example). So all I installed was the Magic Mouse component, not all three (Mouse, Keyboard, Trackpad). Just FYI. It might matter (but I doubt it).

Comment: I'm not a big fan of commercial solutions posted by their sellers!   However ... this product *does* work on Windows 11.  And nothing else does.  Bootcamp and its drivers do not.  Logitech's touch mouse is no longer made.  Microsoft's surface mouse is terrible.  The Apple Magic Mouse is a unique product and this utility makes it work, nicely, on Windows 11.  I hate to reward a sales-pitchy answer but this one is useful.  Mouse only.   The Magic Keyboard just works straight out of the box.  IDK what Magic Utilities would add to that.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply to get the mouse up and running then Apple's drivers will work just fine on a mac or a pc running windows 10 for free. You just can't download them from the apple website directly.

1. Download Brigadier https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier/releases
2. Open up the command line, navigate to the folder with brigadier
3. Run "brigadier.exe" if you are on a mac or "brigadier.exe -m iMac19,2" without quotes on a pc (-m specifies the model's drivers to get. anything recent should have the proper mouse drivers) This will leave a new folder something like bootcamp-###-##### in the directory from where you ran brigadier
4. open Windows Device Manager
5. Under Human Interface Devices right click on the Bluetooth HID device and click update driver
6. Click Browse my computer for driver software, then let me pick, then have disk
7. navigate to the bootcamp folder downloaded with brigadier go to BootCamp\Drivers\Apple\AppleWirelessMouse within this folder and select the AppleWirelessMouse.inf file.
8. Click next. The mouse will not work. This is expected. Just reboot the computer and scrolling will work!

This is a free solution that uses apple's drivers. It seems like for such an expensive piece of hardware they would make the driver easier to install on windows too. I guess that's not the Apple way though.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Rain9333 for his work to make this driver available directly on github. from his comment under the question this download is available here: https://github.com/Rain9333/MagicMouse2DriversWin10x64

Comment: Just to add, you need to run CMD as administrator and ensure you already have 7zip install prior to this.

Comment: There's no "BootCamp\Drivers\Apple\AppleWirelessMouse" folder when I do that (There are other drivers; keyboard, camera etc. but no mouse) The driver in the github repo cannot be installed because of "The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering."