# Apple Magic Mouse 2 scrolling with Windows 11 PC

Tags: windows

Apple Magic Mouse 2 scrolling does not work with Windows 11. The machine is not a Mac.

I've tried the Magic Mouse drivers from the Bootcamp package, as referenced in other questions.   Bootcamp itself won't install.  The driver installs but does nothing. The driver in github referenced in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335276/apple-magic-mouse-2-not-scrolling-magic-mouse-1-works-windows-10-pc)  won't install.

I haven't tried any of these things with Windows 8 or 10, for which they were designed.  Possibly they won't work with 11, I'd like to know if there is a way.

There is no other mouse like the Magic Mouse.  Logitech used to have one, but they stopped making it.  Microsoft makes a wannabe but it's awful.

Comment: Which Mac model/year do you have and which version of the Windows Support Software are you using? Also, how did you manage to install Windows 11? I do not think the Boot Camp Assistant is compatible with Windows 11.

Comment: I am trying to use the Apple mouse with an actual Windows 11 machine.  There is no Apple computer.  You are right about incompatibly ... Hence the question.  I think.

Comment: @SolarMike take the tour!  It's 100% on topic.

Comment: So writing scripts for a windows machine just to make a mouse work is now on topic here? really??

Comment: From the tour: ... "site for Apple enthusiasts" ... "about Apple hardware" ...    This question is literally spot on topic. A question from an Apple enthusiast about a piece of Apple hardware, one that is unique to Apple, and the question happens to be about how to use it in diverse situations.

Comment: The tour does not say "Questions about how to use Apple products in conformance with Apple's strategy to create a closed system where nobody ever uses any hardware or software that is not made by Apple".    And the question does not request a script.  I don't know what the answer will look like.   If I wanted a script I'd just write one.  The interesting part is what is different about the Magic Mouse compared to every other USB mouse on earth.

Comment: However I see now there is a commercial solution offered in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/335292/300770) that does work with Windows 11.   So this question is a duplicate.  I'll try to VtC it myself.

Comment: Glad you found an answer for this already. @SolarMike, I would consider the question to be on-topic but unlikely to get answers :-)